# That's what I take it to mean

Tags: parsing

A: Does it mean ... ?
B: Yes. That's what I take it to mean.

I can't understand at all the way the sentence "*That's what I take it to mean*" is made up.
Is "*that*" the object of "*to mean*"?
Whose object is "*what*"?
Can I remove "*I take it*" and just say "*That's what to say*"?
Could you parse this sentence please?
Could you give me some more sentences having the analogous grammar?

Comment: I can see why the sentence is so confusing. If you don't know that 'I take it' is an idiomatic way of saying 'I understand it' , it must look quite nonsensical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, "take" roughly means "understand".

The sentence overall means, "I understand it to mean that", which implies "*I'm not sure that's correct, but that's what I think right now.*"

I've fleshed out your example to make it easier to describe as I parse it:

> A: In a real estate listing, does "cozy" mean "small"?
> B: [That] is [what I take it to mean].

The sentence you're asking about has a [subject] to the left of "is", and a [subject complement] to the right. "That" refers to "small". "It" is the direct object of "take", and refers to "cozy". "What" is a pronoun acting as the head of the noun clause, "*what I take it to mean*".

The deep structure of "*what I take it to mean*" is: "*I take it to mean what*", where "what" is the *direct object* of "mean". This comes from the structure, *[ "take" + object + "to mean" + something ]*. Some other examples of this structure are:

> I take your silence to mean you're not interested.
> When you picked up your keys, I took that to mean you were going out.

So other ways of wording the entire sentence are:

> I take "cozy" to mean "small".
> What I take "cozy" to mean is "small".

Here's some other examples of the larger structure of the sentence:

> Breakfast in bed! That's what I like on my birthday.
> I failed art. But that's what I was expecting.

You cannot remove "I take it". You'd be left with "That's what to mean", which is nonsense.

Comment: You wrote --- "I take it to mean what", where "what" is the complement of "mean" (not the object of anything) --- as far as I know, "X" is the object in "It means X". And from your words I infer that "X", for some reason, ceases to be the object in "I take it to mean X" and becomes the complement. Am I right? Thanks.

Comment: @Loviii Yes, you might be right that "mean" takes a direct object rather than a complement. It feels like a complement to me because in some sense the meaning of a word is the word itself, but Merriam-Webester agrees with you and calls "mean" a transitive verb in our context. I'm not confident enough to dispute them, so I have changed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

*'That'* - something already mentioned.

*'is'*

*'what'* - the thing that he understands as the meaning

*'I take it'* - I understand it (idomatic)

*'to mean'*

No, you cannot remove 'I take it', but you could replace it with 'I understand it'.